# Does Maven 3.5.2 supports Java11 builds

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, maven-3, java-11

In Jenkins, currently there is only JDK8 and maven 3.5.2 installed. I downloaded JDK11 to it. I ran a pipeline project to build a springboot Java11 project and it ran fine using maven 3.5.2. There is no reference to any maven source or target versions in the pom of the project. Currently I don't see any issues with JDK11 with maven 3.5.2 due to simplicity of the project. Any idea if it might cause issues with complex projects? Is it good to update Maven version in Jenkins and the spring boot projects?

Comment: First if you not have any issues than it's fine but I don't know why you are using such an old version https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi (3.8.2) in the meantime...and you should always set the correct version (source/target is for JDK9+ not the correct way..better use `<maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>` instead...

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html  Maven 3.5.2 needed JDK7 at minimum...